# Open an application after wake from sleep

Tags: macos, applications, macbook-pro, sleep-wake

Is is possible for an application to open up after waking up your MacBook?
So I have this application that I want it to open every time that I wake up my Macbook from  sleep.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [SleepWatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de), an app that lets you…

> execute a Unix command when the Mac or the display of the Mac … wakes up

Such a command to open an app could be:

```
open /Applications/Safari.app
```